# Usage of Community-wiki

Tags: discussion, policy, community-wiki

In some other communities, there have been discussions about the use of the "Community wiki"-function. The policies seem to differ from site to site, so before it comes to any problems here about what should be CW'ed and what should be deleted: What is our stance?

References:

- [The Future of Community Wiki (on blog.SE)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) (Official Stance of SE, it seems)
- [A similar discussion on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/516/should-every-opinion-question-be-community-wiki) (As a reference for possible stances on the topic)

(Feel free to add to this list)

Answer (score 11):

I am strongly in favor of adopting the official stance of Stack Exchange, both because I agree with it (a good question doesn't need to be CW, and a bad question is not excused by CW; moderators can use their judgement in exceptional circumstances), and because I won't deviate from the official stance without having a good reason (i.e. if we should deviate, the burden of proof is on those who want to deviate).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I still think CW is suitable for are aggregating answers to list questions (see [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7900/1546) for a good example), and we have kind-of [decided](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-about-list-questions) not to do those.